# Parse callback comes really slow and does not work properly

Tags: android, callback

I am using Parse server for my Android app, but when clicking a button for callback I get the logged info some really long time after I click and nothing actually happends - it does not login or register my users. It does not also show any errors in the logcat so I really have no idea what went wrong

here is my activity -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnKeyListener {

    EditText tvID, tvPassword;
    TextView tvLoginOrRegister;
    Button signupButton;
    LinearLayout backgroundLayout;
    ImageView logoImageView;
    Boolean signupModeActive = true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initViews();
    }

    private void onLoginOrSignButtonClicked() {
        Log.i("button", "was clicked");
        String user = tvID.getText().toString();
        String pass = tvPassword.getText().toString();
        if (user.isEmpty() || pass.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "user & pass are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            if (signupModeActive) {
                //We are going to signup
                signup(user, pass);
            } else {
                //We are going to log in
                login(user, pass);
            }
        }
    }

    private void login(String user, String pass) {
        ParseUser.logInInBackground(user, pass, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                if (user != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "login okay", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseUser> objects, ParseException e) {
                            if (e == null && objects != null){
                                Log.i("list of users", objects.toString());
                            } else {
                                Log.i("users list error", e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void signup(String user, String pass) {
        ParseUser newUser = new ParseUser();
        newUser.setUsername(user);
        newUser.setPassword(pass);
        newUser.signUpInBackground(new SignUpCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseException e) {
                Log.i("callback", "came back from callback");
                if (e == null) {
                    Log.i("signup", "success");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "signup success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnRegister:
                onLoginOrSignButtonClicked();
                break;
            case R.id.tvLoginOrRegister:
                Log.i("switch", "was tapped");
                if (signupModeActive) {
                    setSignupOrLoginText(false, "Login", "Or, Signup");
                } else {
                    setSignupOrLoginText(true, "Sign Up", "Or, Login");
                }
                break;
            case R.id.logoImageview:
            case R.id.backgroundLayout:
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);

                break;
        }
    }

    private void setSignupOrLoginText(Boolean login, String buttonText, String textviewText) {
        signupModeActive = login;
        signupButton.setText(buttonText);
        tvLoginOrRegister.setText(textviewText);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
        if (i == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER && keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            onLoginOrSignButtonClicked();
        }

        return false;
    }

    private void initViews() {
        tvID = findViewById(R.id.tvId);
        tvPassword = findViewById(R.id.tvPassword);
        signupButton = findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        tvLoginOrRegister = findViewById(R.id.tvLoginOrRegister);
        backgroundLayout = findViewById(R.id.backgroundLayout);
        logoImageView = findViewById(R.id.logoImageview);
        signupButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvLoginOrRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
        tvPassword.setOnKeyListener(this);
        logoImageView.setOnClickListener(this);
        backgroundLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
```

as I mentioned before, nothing appears on the logcat on error or info so I really have no idea why it is not responding. Hopefully someone can point out what I did wrong.

Comment: remove ` ParseQuery` from one of your methods and see if you can get anything.

Comment: @P4yam I don't get it correctly, which method do you mean?

Comment: for example in `login` method and after `done` remove your `parseQuery` and just make a log to see if anything is happening.

Comment: @P4yam noting happends. I get this line in the begginjng:

? I/chatty: uid=10086(com.parse.starter) identical 10 lines

but nothing more than that. it just does not respond to neither login or register

Comment: Can you check if you can login users with Postman? are you sure your server is working fine?

Comment: @P4yam how do I do so with Parse? I have the server domain, client key and appId but I don't know the query pattern

Comment: Check this link: https://docs.parseplatform.org/rest/guide/